# Can't pass command line arguments to an NSTask running the PHP CLI

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstask

Edit: [Solved] see below.

I'm launching PHP as an `NSTask` and trying to pass some command line options to it:

```
NSTask *php = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[php setLaunchPath: phpPath];
NSArray *args = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"-r 'echo 123;'", nil ];
[php setArguments: args];
[php launch];
```

When I run this from Objective-C I always get the following PHP errors:

**For:**
@"-r 'echo 123;'"
@"-r \'echo 123;\'"
@"-r \"echo 123;\""
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in Command line code on line 1`

**For:**
@"-r 'echo \'hello\';'"
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Command line code on line 1`

**For:**
@"--run 'echo 123;'"
`Usage: php [options] ...`

It should be noted that all errors are reported from the PHP interpreter when called from Objective-C, but when I try the exact same option string on the command line, it works as expected.

What's wrong here? how should I write arguments to be correctly passed to the NSTask?

PS: My real goal is to execute some `include()` lines instead of the echo, which doesn't work either, and instead I get an error of an unexpected Encapsed String.

Comment: Unlikely to make a difference but what if you use `echo(123);` instead of `echo 123;`?

Comment: No that's not it, anyway I already found the solution, see below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I saw it on another question.
I'm treating `-r 'echo 123;'` as a single argument, when in fact they're two, it should be:
`NSArray *args = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"-r", @"echo 123;", nil ];`
Sorry! and thanks.